# Llenar una matriz con asteriscos figurando un rombo

Tags: java

El usuario tiene que introducir un número non, pero menor que 65.
El número ingresado debe ser mandado a una matriz bidimensional de dicho número ingresado, para ser llenado con asteriscos dándole una forma de rombo.
Por ejemplo, ingresas 5 y la matriz deberá ser de 5x5.

```
            LENGUAJE JAVA:    

package Concurso;
import java.util.*;
public class Problema_3 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int a=sc.nextInt();
    int b=a;
    if((a%2)!=0) {
      char [][] matriz=new char[a][b];
      
      for(int i=0; i<a;i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<b; j++) {
          if((i+j) >=2 && (j-i) <=2) {
            matriz [i][j]='*';
          }
          else {
            matriz[i][j]=' ';
          }
          System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
      }
    }
  }
}

AL INTRODUCIR EL NÚMERO 5 POR EJEMPLO
 ME DA DE SALIDA
    *      
  * * *    
* * * * *  
* * * * *  
* * * * *
```

SOLO FALTA ACOMODAR LA MITAD, PERO NO SE COMO, ALGUIEN QUE ME AYUDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En los cambios se separó el llenado de la matriz de la impresión. Cuando se va llenado la primera mitad del rombo al mismo tiempo se va copiando a la otra mitad para lograr la simetría.

Se agregó el cálculo del centro `int centro = (a / 2);` para que genere rombos de cualquier tamaño.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = a;
        if ((a % 2) != 0) {
            char[][] matriz = new char[a][b];

            int centro = (a / 2);

            for (int i = 0; i <= centro; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
                    if ((i + j) >= centro && (j - i) <= centro) {
                        matriz[i][j] = '*';
                    } else {
                        matriz[i][j] = ' ';
                    }

                    // llenar la otra mitad
                    matriz[(matriz.length - 1) - i][j] = matriz[i][j];

                }
            }
            // impresión de la matriz
            for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }


        }
    }
```

**Actualización**

Lo que se hace para llenar la otra mitad es copiar la primer fila a la última, la segunda a la penúltima y así.

Con el código:

```
matriz[(matriz.length - 1) - i][j] = matriz[i][j];
```

`(matriz.length - 1)` es la última fila. A la última fila se le resta el valor actual de `i` quedando así: `(matriz.length - 1) - i`, lo que se logra con eso es ir cambiando la fila a la que se copiará la fila `i` fila conforme `i` se va incrementando. Por ejemplo: si el rombo es de 5, cuando `i` sea 0 se copiará la fila 0 a la fila 4, cuando  `i` sea uno, se copiará la fila 1 a la fila 3, cuando `i` sea 2 se copiará la fila 2 a la fila 2 ( el centro del rombo ). El valor de `j` no cambia porque ese apunta a la columna.

Comment: Wow brother, eres genial!! gracias por explicarme que onda, además por el código y los comentarios te la rifaste! Gracias encerio!!

Comment: Me podrías explicar un poco lo del llenado de la otra mitad? Bueno, esque quiero entenderlo por mi propia cuenta pero no logro saber que es lo que hace

Comment: Sí, claro. Agregué una explicación a la respuesta.

Comment: Wow brother! Mis respetos,muchas gracias, logré comprenderlo al 100. Te sigo en esta plataforma! Un cordial saludo.